# What light bulb can replace an 25 watt R45?

Tags: light, bulb

I need to find a replacement light bulb for my kitchen hutch.  I can't find the 25 Watt R45 specified anywhere.  With what can I replace it with?

Comment: R45 doesn't fully describe the bulb [they can have different fittings, screw & bayonet, potentially each in 2 sizes]. Take a photo of it to save confusion & type out exactly what it says on the side, for clarification. [It's commonly an E27 but I'd like to be sure]

Comment: Where are you? Quick answer would be and R45 is a Reflector lamp 45/8ths of inch diameter, likely med E26/E27 depending on continent. If a 5" diameter lamp vs 5 5/8 would look OK try searching for R40. That's about 1/4" bigger clearance around bulb.

Comment: any mains-powered LED bulb that will fit should work, doesn't have to be exact. If that area gets really hot, go for halogen, which are still widely available. That said, amazon has your orig...